# Python Attrs Trigger Converter while set attribute

Tags: python, validation, python-attrs

While using python-attrs, what is the good way to trigger the converter while set the attribute.

EX:

```
@attr.s
class A(object):
   b = attr.ib(converter=str)

>>> A(b=1)
A(b='1')
>>> a = A(b=1)
>>> a.b
'1'
>>> a.b = 2
>>> a.b
2   # converter not used
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you cannot do that using attrs, by the [reference of philosophy](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/overview.html#philosophy):  attrs runtime impact is very close to zero because all the work is done when the class is defined. Once you’ve initialized it, attrs is out of the picture completely.

To see what the attrs real does:

```
import attr
import inspect


@attr.s
class A(object):
    b = attr.ib(converter=str)


print(inspect.getsource(A.__init__))
```

the output is

```
def __init__(self, b):
    self.b = __attr_converter_b(b)
```

So you can see all the magic is only done in the init function, so after the instance is initialized, attrs cannot handle it anymore, if you really want to control your own set behavior, why not using the descriptor, which is designed for class attributes.

Comment: Thanks but, there is a attr.validate(obj). I don't see the reason we don't have something like attr.conv(obj) or attr.validate(obj, convert=True)